# Create ether wallet account using node js and web3

Tags: web3js, myetherwallet, nodejs, ethereumjs

Hello I want to create a ether wallet account using node js and web3. Can anyone please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

1st make sure you have web3 installed.

```
npm install web3
```

then add the following to one of your nodejs files.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword').then(console.log);
> '0x1234567891011121314151617181920212223456'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I got this error Cannot read property 'newAccount' of undefined. I am working in ropsten test environment .Could you pls help further

Comment: you will need to ensure that you start geth with the right parameters that allow you to access "personal".  Have a look at this command | geth --identity "MyNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "127.0.0.1"  --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 1999 console | note the word "personal"  if your node has not explicitly been told to allow access then trying to call web3.eth.personal will not work.

Comment: It does not return private key. Can you please tell how can i get that?

Comment: You should be able to find that answer by doing some googling

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to create a Wallet Address is as follows:
Assume you already have your web3 object connected.

```
createWallet = cb => {
  cb(web3.eth.accounts.create());
};
```

Then call it like this

```
createWallet(result => {
  console.log("Wallet Add is:", result.address);
  console.log("Private Key is:", result.privateKey);
});
```

Hope that helps. This article also helps to distinguish: This article should help understand the difference between the 2 methods.
[Difference between creation methods](https://medium.com/@andthentherewere0/should-i-use-web3-eth-accounts-or-web3-eth-personal-for-account-creation-15eded74d0eb)